I am getting an grafana panel error when I use neo4j's apoc in a cypher query
I am able to return a valid cypher query from Neo4j 5 using the apoc plugin. I am getting an error in Grafana when I am using the apoc plugin in a query.
The query works in Neo4j but I get the error when I run it from Grafana.
I reinstalled the plugin, ensured the environment variables are set

Solved my own problem. There were some values in the JSON that were boolean and Grafana didn't like it. used the toString() cypher on all returned values - problem fixed.
...
WITH apoc.convert.fromJsonMap(n.attributes) AS jsonObject
UNWIND keys(jsonObject) AS key
WITH key, toString(jsonObject[key]) AS value
RETURN key, value

